# Android Google Map - how to display all address of matching location?

Tags: android, android-maps

I have a form in which user will type his address but i want to create such widget for address so that whenever user types his address, then all similiar location will be listed in the suggestion box and user can select his location.

Similiar functionality i have seen in google map navigation application. 
Can you please tell me how create such feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about matching places for a street address, this should work:

1. use reverse geocoding to convert it into (latitude, longitude) pair, both [Android itself](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) and [Google API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) provides this service;
2. use [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/) to obtain nearby places using the pair of coordinates

I have a project which actually does the similar job, while due to some reasons it is not public, but I can assure you this way could work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I got something while studying Google Api that when we search any place, then in the background it sends my text in the google map url and in reverse it sends the list of longitude and latitude of matching location. I think that i can convert that list of long/lat in the list of places. M i saying right.